# draw dictionary in an adventure game

Tags: dictionary, pygame, draw

I've been programming my adventure game and I'd like to display my dictionary.
I'm unfortunately not familiar with for loops. 
The dictionary should display my items which are stored in a different class.
The items are not displaying in different rows. They merge into each other.
hopefully someone can help me out.

"""

```
for k, v in self.hero_dic_items.items():
    BATTLE.draw_dmg(k, 110, 150, 10, self.black)
    BATTLE.draw_dmg(v, 200, 150, 10, self.black)
```

"""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever argument to `draw_dmg` that specifies the y-coordinate to draw at needs to be *different* for each object.  For example, you could have a variable `y` initialized to the location for the 1st item, and add enough to it inside the loop so that each *next* item will be drawn far enough down not to overlap.  Something like `y = y + 10` (or whatever number is appropriate).

Comment: The y variable has to change. I'm aware of that but I don't know how to realize that. It's a game. so I'm in a menu and I click on items and they should appear in different rows. so i cant change the y coordinate in my draw function during the game.